# How to check if two raycast hit points in unity3d arcore are same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am working on a project in unity and arcore, where I need to scan the area and mark points in AR.

These points in ARcore, when once completed a circuit (that is when 1st point meets the last point), I need to create a polygon.

How can I find out whether first point and last point are at same location.

Also let me know if this method is right to create a polygon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a listener to the node where your object was added.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html